# Loading cross domain XML with Javascript using a hybrid iframe-proxy/xsl/jsonp concept?

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-domain, cross-site

On our site `www.foo.com` we want to download and use `http://feeds.foo.com/feed.xml` with Javascript. We'll obviously use [Access-Control](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) but for browsers that don't support it we are considering the following as a fallback:

**On `www.foo.com`**, we set `document.domain`, provide a callback function and load the feed into a (hidden) `iframe`:

```
document.domain = 'foo.com';
function receive_data(data) {
 // process data
};

var proxy = document.createElement('iframe');
proxy.src = 'http://feeds.foo.com/feed.xml';
document.body.appendChild(proxy);
```

**On `feeds.foo.com`**, add an XSL to `feed.xml` and use it to transform the feed into an html document that also sets `document.domain` and calls the callback function in its parent with the feed data as json:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="ROOT">
  <html><body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain = 'foo.com';
    parent.receive_data([<xsl:apply-templates/>]);
   </script>
  </body></html>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- templates that transform data into json objects go here -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Is there a better way to load XML from feeds.foo.com and what are the ramifications of this iframe-proxy/xslt/jsonp trick? (..and in what cases will it fail?)**

---

*Remarks*

- This does not work in Safari & Chrome but since both support [Access-Control](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) it's fine.
- We want little or no change to `feeds.foo.com`
- We are aware of (but not interested in) server-side proxy solutions
- *update:* [wrote about it](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/cross-sub-domain-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over both domains, you can try a cross-domain scripting library like [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/), which wraps cross-browser quirks and provides an easy-to-use API for communicating in client script between different domains using the best available mechanism for that browser (e.g. [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) if available, other mechanisms if not).

Caveat: you need to have control over both domains in order to make it work (where "control" means you can place static files on both of them).  But you don't need any server-side code changes.

Another Caveat: there are security implications here-- make sure you trust the other domain's script!

Comment: just so you know, with easyXDM there is no need to trust the other party - the two documents only communicate via strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use yahoo apis ([YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)).. Just specify url, format and callback

- [Cross domain requests with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) by James Padolsey
- [jQuery plugin](http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/)

It's kind of server-side solution, however not on your server :)

Comment: I've actually used YQL before and liked it (apart of some interesting caching phenomena you can't control). Unfortunately we don't really want to introduce this dependency for several reasons.